# Need help to find the value of L and C

Tags: systems-of-equations, computational-mathematics

[image for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI4PZ.jpg)

This is an electrical question but i stuck in two equations that i am unable to solve it further that need mathematics. so i am asking here, basically the two equation are these

> ## $\displaystyle\frac{150(1-w^{2}LC)+150w^{2}LC}{(1-w^{2}LC)^{2}+(150wC)^{2}}=200$
>
> ## $\displaystyle\frac{wL(1-w^{2}LC)-22500wC}{(1-w^{2}LC)^{2}+(150wC)^{2}}=300$

where $w=2\pi f$ and $f=685 kHz$

> Is there any way i can get the value of L and C?

Comment: First clear the denominators by multiplying each equation by the denominator of its LHS. Then start with the first equation by treating $C$ as a variable and $L$ as a constant. Rearrange to get a quadratic in $C$ and use the quadratic formula to solve, obtaining a formula for $C$ in terms of $L$. Plug this into the second equation to obtain an equation depending only on $L$ (hopefully a quadratic as well; I haven't tried it).

Comment: Take $x=l ,y=c$
$$\displaystyle\frac{150(1-w^{2}xy)+150w^{2}xy}{(1-w^{2}xy)^{2}+(150wy)^{2}}=200\\
\displaystyle\frac{wL(1-w^{2}xy)-22500wy}{(1-w^{2}xy)^{2}+(150wy)^{2}}=300\\$$and plot them by a software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to take $$x=w^2LC\\y=150wC \\\to \\\frac{x}{y}=\frac{wL}{150}$$so 
$$\displaystyle\frac{150(1-x)+150x}{(1-x)^{2}+(y)^{2}}=200\\
\displaystyle\frac{wL(1-x)-150y}{(1-x)^{2}+(y)^{2}}=300 \to 
\\\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{150(1-x)+150x}{(1-x)^{2}+(y)^{2}}=200\\\displaystyle\frac{\frac{x}{y}(1-x)-150y}{(1-x)^{2}+(y)^{2}}=300\end{cases} $$ then find x,y with graphing  ,then find $L,C$ I graph it ,follow the below link 
  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o9zyhiveqn
[image]